# Turn a script into a function

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a script that successfully creates a new column in the existing data frame, using mutate combined with str_detect to indicate whether a drug component is present in the old variable. I would like to turn this script into a function to make it easier to use repetitively. My attempts to create the function have failed.

Here is the script:

```
Drug_Table_Names <- data.frame(mutate(
    Drug_Table_Names, 
    DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, 
    Flurbiprofen = str_detect(Drug_Table_Names$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"FLURBIPROFEN", negate = FALSE)
))
```

The script finds Flurbiprofen in the column DRUG_GENERIC_NAME  and creates a new column named FLUBIPROFEN  which TRUE if Flurbiprofen is present.

My attempt to create a function `FlagDrugNames` was written this way:

```
function(drug_flag, gen_name){
    Drug_Table_Names <- data.frame(mutate(
        Drug_Table_Names, 
        DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, 
        drug_flag = str_detect(Drug_Table_Names$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,
                               "gen_name", negate = FALSE)
    ))
}
```

Where `drug_flag` is the string the function looks for, in the example above is is Flurbiprofen, and gen_name is the name of the column it creates. This function does not work.

I would appreciate any help with the function.

Comment: In the function `str_detect` is looking for the *literal* `"gen_name"`, not the value of a *function argument* `gen_name`. Also, 1) in `str_detect` argument `negate = FALSE` is already the default; 2) the last function code line should be return value, `Drug_Table_Names`.

Comment: More things: 1. `mutate` already returns a data frame. If you want to untibble, use `as.data.frame`. 2. Putting `DRUG_GENERIC_NAME` in `mutate` doesn't do anything. 3. Generally don't use `$` inside of dplyr functions; use the bare column name. 4. If you need to set a column name in a function in `mutate`, [you'll have to use `:=`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). 5. You should assign the function to something and supply some sample data and a call [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Rui Barradas is correct. I would add that your data argument isn't quite right. Your function takes in `drug_flag` and `gen_name`. I presume `drug_flag` is the data, but within the function you use `Drug_Table_Names` as data. The only thing you do with `drug_flag` is assign the output of `str_detect` to it.

Comment: Thank you: Follow up questions/comments:  To Rui Barradas, how do I write the function so that   I can enter the string I'm looking for as an argument, which was the intent of of gen_name?  I  added the line

Comment: continuation of previous comment, ... return, Drug_Table_Names and got a tibble rather than a modification of the original data frame. How do I change the output so that it modifies the data fram?

Answer (score 1):

Like it is said in the comments, the code in the question is complicating what can be made much simpler.

```
library(tidyverse)

flagCol <- function(DF, gen_name){
  DF %>%
    mutate(drug_flag = str_detect(DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, gen_name))
}
```

Test the function with an example data set.

```
Drug_Table_Names <- letters[1:10]
DRUG_GENERIC_NAME <- LETTERS[1:10] 

df1 <- data.frame(Drug_Table_Names, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME)

flagCol(df1, "G")
#   Drug_Table_Names DRUG_GENERIC_NAME drug_flag
#1                 a                 A     FALSE
#2                 b                 B     FALSE
#3                 c                 C     FALSE
#4                 d                 D     FALSE
#5                 e                 E     FALSE
#6                 f                 F     FALSE
#7                 g                 G      TRUE
#8                 h                 H     FALSE
#9                 i                 I     FALSE
#10                j                 J     FALSE
```

**Edit**

The OP asks two questions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822886/turn-a-script-into-a-function/56827325#comment100209885_56827325).

Question 2:

> I want the name of the new variable, which is drug_flag in your
>   example above, to be the same as the string I look for with
>   str_detect. It there a way to add an argument to the function so that
>   it will accept the same character string as the value of gen_name?

Yes, there is. The function below does that, and doesn't need package `dplyr` loaded, only package `stringr`. It accepts an extra argument, `DRUG_COL` with default set to `"DRUG_GENERIC_NAME"`, the name of the column where to look for `gen_name`.

```
flagCol2 <- function(DF, gen_name, DRUG_COL = "DRUG_GENERIC_NAME"){
  DF[[gen_name]] <- str_detect(DF[[DRUG_COL]], gen_name)
  DF
}

flagCol2(df1, "G")
#   Drug_Table_Names DRUG_GENERIC_NAME     G
#1                 a                 A FALSE
#2                 b                 B FALSE
#3                 c                 C FALSE
#4                 d                 D FALSE
#5                 e                 E FALSE
#6                 f                 F FALSE
#7                 g                 G  TRUE
#8                 h                 H FALSE
#9                 i                 I FALSE
#10                j                 J FALSE
```

Question 1 (my emphasis):

> It currently returns a tibble and I want it to add the new variable to
>   the original data frame which is Drug_Table_Names. How do I **modify the
>   function** to do that.

There is no need to modify the functions, both `flagCol` and `flagCol2` do that. All it needs to be done is to assign the result back to the original dataframe.

```
df1 <- flagCol(df1, "G")
```

Or the second version.

```
df1 <- flagCol2(df1, "G")
```

**Edit 2.**

Multiple genes passed to the function.

```
flagCol3 <- function(DF, gen_name, DRUG_COL = "DRUG_GENERIC_NAME"){
  for(gn in gen_name){
    DF[[gn]] <- str_detect(DF[[DRUG_COL]], gn)
  }
  DF
}

# There is no gene "X", but the column is created
df3 <- flagCol3(df1, c("B", "G", "X"))
```

Comment: Thank you, This works as advertised. Questions: 1) It currently returns a tibble and I want it to add the new variable to the original data frame which is Drug_Table_Names.  How do I modify the function to do that. 2) I want the name of the new variable, which is drug_flag in your example above, to be the same as the string I look for with str_detect.  It there a way to  add an argument to the function so that it will accept the same character string as the value of gen_name?

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. There is one more thing I would like to be able to do with this function: Is there a way to send a list of names for the argument gen_name so that the function can run a series of names?

Comment: @StevenHahn Edit 2 implements that, function `flagCol3`.